# How do i calculate Ranks based on score?

Tags: database, data-structures

There is a platform on which we rank users based on their points. Let's say there are about 10,000 entries. And database looks something like below.

| Id | UserName | Points | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Archit | 0 | 4 |
| 1 | Archit1 | 15 | 1 |
| 2 | Archit2 | 10 | 2 |
| 3 | Archit3 | 5 | 3 |

Whenever somebody does an action their point increases or decreases, based on that I also need to update the Rank in the database. But the problem is that updating it, again and again, every time somebody does action is a very slow process.
And also calculating the rank while showing it on the profile is also not a good way.

What should be the ideal solution to such a problem?

Answer (score 1):

To make it efficient you should change only ranks changed, and not recalculate the whole data every time.

As you haven't specified programming language, here is an example pseudo code:

```
-- input variables: CurrID, PointChange
CurrRank = Rank[CurrID]
Points[CurrID] = Points[CurrID] + PointChange
CurrPoints = Points[CurrID]
NewRank = SELECT count(Id) From YourTable where Points >= CurrPoints
if NewRank > CurrRank Then
  update YourTable Rank = Rank - 1 where Rank > CurrRank And Rank <= NewRank
else
  update YourTable Rank = Rank + 1 where Rank <= CurrRank And Rank > NewRank
end if
Rank[CurrID] = newRank
```

Comment: What if there is a person A with 1st Rank, person B with 2nd Rank, and person C with 3rd Rank, Person C gains score, and his rank changes to 1st. Now you mean that I should only update person C and person A. What will happen to a person B in between? Logically i person B should also be updated.

Comment: I don't say only person A and C. If you have a change, like rank 3rd to 8th, then you need to change everybody with original rank between 3rd and 8th (but don't change ranks 1st, 2nd and from 9th to end). That's also what the code does.

Comment: Oh okay got it. Thanks.